# cannot display vue data array in html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

so I'm getting the price of a bitcoin and I'm then storing it in a data array of a new vue instance, when I try to console.log this array in my js file it perfectly works but when I try to display it in my html like so `{{ array }}` it displays an empty array.

```js
var newApp = new Vue({
    el: '#api-app',
    data: {
    message: 'hello',
    bitcoin: null
    },
    mounted(){
        const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
        const url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=1&convert=EUR"
        const headers = {
            headers: {
                'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '6adgg52e-3950-4a2c-bgbb-991e41065c5c'//dummy api key
              }
          }

        axios(proxyurl + url, {headers})
        .then(result => {
           this.bitcoin = result.data
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error("error",err)
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="api-app">
    <ul v-for="(details,index) in bitcoin" :key="index">
        <li>Rank: <strong>{{ details.name }}st</strong><br>Price: <strong>{{ details.price_eur }}€</strong></li>              
   </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.10/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong you may have to v-for in your html, to display array data

Comment: @MSoheb tried that in my code doesn't work updated my snippet aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
axios(proxyurl + url, {headers})
    .then(result => {
        this.bitcoin = result.data
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error("error",err)
    })
```

This should work.

It is working. Check your response there is no **price** field.

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "9287.63433026", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "22493494863.2", 
        "market_cap_usd": "167413899690", 
        "available_supply": "18025462.0", 
        "total_supply": "18025462.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.12", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.85", 
        "percent_change_7d": "0.2", 
        "last_updated": "1572697240", 
        "price_eur": "8316.11062878", 
        "24h_volume_eur": "20140585326.6", 
        "market_cap_eur": "149901736127"
    }
]
```

use the correct **attribute name**.

Comment: @SimpleDev can you show me what response you are getting from the request and what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: @SimpleDev **Response** does not contain any **price** field. Rank is showing perfectly when i run the snippet. Check the updated answer, i have given the response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reactivity caveats in Vue JS:
You should check out those here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

In your case, you're defining a blank array and then directly assigning a new array after the request is successful. Hence it is changing the length of the array and it becomes non-reactive.

In an ideal way, you should set `bitcoin:null` and put `v-if='bitcoin'` before rendering the UI. So the template will not render until the response has arrived and you can also set a nice loader in `v-else`.

Comment: Tried that still doesn't work, it doesnt display anything

Comment: Does vue-devtools show the bitcoin array filled with values?